# Integrating Zenoss (mail data Logs) with MySql database table?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, zenoss

I have installed Zenoss monitoring tool on my pc and I want to store every outgoing email from the zenoss to a database. Does any one know how I can achieve this. FYI I just use this server to send emails and I use google Apps to receive emails. And i want to store all this mail to my MySql table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to store the e-mails? Events are already stored in Zenoss's MySQL database? The e-mails are generated from the events. You can customize Zenoss's archive settings under the advanced tab - events in the left hand menu. You can query the tables like normal, and I suppose you could copy those tables too if you wanted...

Comment: where i can see those events would you please elaborate it.

Comment: Look in the zenoss_zep database ... that's where the events are stored.

Comment: ya i have already seen it but i have not found where the mail data which i am getting.(that is in which table it has).

Comment: Is the information you want in the event view in the Web UI? If so, that's in the event table in MySQL. If you mean the email template, that's in the settings in the WebUI, filled out like a form letter / mail merge with data from the event table.